# Issue in install java jdk in RHEL(Linux)

Tags: java, rhel

I tried to install `jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin`on `Linux`. I used `sh jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin`to run.

But I got following errors. 
[image]

Is there issue with installer? or is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Run the rpm using `-x` option to get debug information. That shall help identifying the root cause.

Use `sh -x jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin` to install the rpm and see what all operations does the shell performs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. There was an  issue in installation package, I downloaded `jdk-6u23-linux-i586-rpm.bin` and it works fine.